# How is God a rock (Psalm 18:2, 31; 19:14)? Is it in the same sense as Psalm 18:46 and Psalm 61:2?

Tags: bible-versions

How is God a rock?

> **Psalm 18:2 (KJV)**
>   The Lord is my **rock**, and my fortress, and my deliverer; my God, my strength, in whom I will trust; my buckler, and the horn of my salvation, and my high tower.
>
> **Psalm 18:31 (KJV)**
>   For who is God save the Lord? or who is a **rock** save our God?
>
> **Psalm 19:14 (KJV)**
>   Let the words of my mouth, and the meditation of my heart, be acceptable in thy sight, O Lord, my **strength[rock]**, and my redeemer.

Is it the same sense as in:

> **Psalm 18:46 (KJV)**
>   The Lord liveth; and blessed be my **rock**; and let the God of my salvation be exalted.
>
> **Psalm 61:2 (KJV)**
>   From the end of the earth will I cry unto thee, when my heart is overwhelmed: lead me to the **rock** that is higher than I.

The Message Bible puts Psalm 61:2 this way:

> When I'm far from anywhere, down to my last gasp, I call out, "Guide me up High Rock Mountain!"

David must have been far from home when he wrote this psalm.  Fortunately, God is not limited to any geographic locale.  Even when we’re among strange people and surroundings, God never abandons us.  His all-surpassing strength is always with us.

Answer (score 1):

In Bible, rock is a metaphor of secure, firm and unchangeable. The authors of the Psalm use rock to emphasize these nature of the Lord.

It was first being used in Jacob's blessing to his sons. Subsequently 'Rock' becomes a synonym to the God of Israel.

> because of the hand of the **Mighty One of Jacob**,
> because of the Shepherd, **the Rock of Israel**, (Gen 49:24b NIV)

Q1: How is God a rock?

God is not 'a' rock. God is 'the' rock or 'my' rock. I'm not sure why KJV put 'a rock' in Psalm 18:31, but NIV version is

> For who is God besides the Lord?
> And who is **the Rock** except our God? (Psalm 18:31 NIV)

The context in Psalm 61:1-2 doesn't fit the same sense 'the rock' means God. For it sounds quite odd to read "O God, lead me to God".

> 1 Hear my cry, **O God**;
> listen to my prayer.
>
> 2 From the ends of the earth I call to you,
> I call as my heart grows faint;
> **lead me to the rock** that is higher than I. (Psalm 61:1-2 NIV)

The Ellicott's Commentary is a reasonable interpretation

> Lead me to the rock . . .--Literally, upon the rock lead me, which is probably a *constructio prægnans* for lead me to the rock too high for me to climb by myself, and place me there. **The elevated rock is a symbol of security**, which cannot be obtained without the Divine help. Others take the expression as figurative for a difficulty which it needs God's help to surmount.

Answer (score 0):

A rock in this context seems to refer to a vantage point or refuge in a battle. Notice that each passage describes God as not only a rock but also a footrace and salvation. Just as a rock delivers in wartime, God delivers in Spiritual warfare.

Answer (score 0):

All but the first passage are using the Hebrew צוּרִ֥ (tsur), meaning "rock", "cliff" or "stone".  It is frequently employed as a metaphor to describe God as a stable, unchanging and secure foundation for His people, as illustrated in some of the other verses you chose.

In the Septuagint, צוּרִ֥ is usually translated as πέτρα (*petra*) in Greek - the same word used in Matthew 16:18 and elsewhere in the New Testament.

---

The word used in Psalm 18:2 is סַֽלְעִ֥ (*selah*), which can mean "cliff", "crag" or also "rock".  It is also used as a metaphor for God.  It is the word used, for example, in Psalm 62:6-7

> *He only is my rock* [סַֽלְעִ֥] *and my salvation: He is my defence; I shall not be moved. In God is my salvation and my glory: The rock*
> [סַֽלְעִ֥] *of my strength, and my refuge, is in God.*

סַֽלְעִ֥ is also translated as πέτρα in the Septuagint.

---

There are only subtle distinctions between צוּר and סֶלַע.

צוּר is generally used to describe a large, immovable rock or a rocky formation, such as a mountain or a cliff face. It often connotes stability, strength, and protection.

On the other hand, סֶלַע is generally used to describe a large, jagged rock or rocky outcropping, often used for shelter or defense. It can also be used metaphorically to describe people or things that are strong, steadfast, and unyielding. For example, in Job 30:6, Job speaks of the outcasts who *dwell in the clifts* (בַּסְּלָעִ֑ים) *of the valleys, in caves of earth and in the rocks* (בַסְּלָעִֽים).